# Making Vue.js detect changes to array using $set()

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having trouble updating an array that is displayed as a list. I'm trying to make Vue detect the changes using $set() (as explained in the [documentation](http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Caveats)), but I can't make it work.

Here's my code:

```
this.choices = this.currentScene.choices;
for (i = 0; i < this.choices.length; i++) {
  choice = this.currentScene.choices[i];
  choice.parsedText = this.parseText(choice.text);
  this.choices.$set(i, choice);
}
```

Vue still doesn't update the view. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Yes, "this" refers to the Vue instance.

Comment: if `this` is the Vue instance, then `this.choices.$set` doesn't exists, because Vue defines a `this.$set` method for the instance, not for its data

Comment: @YerkoPalma nope, the way OP is using it is correct as well.

Comment: really? I've never seen it like that in the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would definitely be useful to have a JSfiddle of your code, but I'm going to take a crack anyways.

I'm not sure you need to use that function to update the array, since as the documentation points out, its only when you need to change the index of the item.

JavaScript has a built in function called `.map` that takes a callback function and returns a new array with the callback applied to each item.

For example, you could translate your function to this, assuming that `.parseText` is a method on the Vue class.

```
var self = this; // so that we can access the Vue class inside map

this.choices = this.currentScene.choices.map(function(choice) {
    choice.parsedText = self.parseText(choice.text);
    return choice;
});
```

And Vue should pick up those changes.

Comment: Just wanted to suggest using `map` since each item in the array is being modified. Here's a fiddle I made to supplement the answer I don't have to write now ;) http://jsfiddle.net/ch12nc6j/1/

Comment: That's excellent, you even mocked a modified return value in the function to illustrate! kudos.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses! However I was not able to get it to work even with the jsfiddle example... I couldn't figure out how to load json files in jsfiddle so I hosted it on my own server: http://nano.fi/gametest

The updateChoices() function is on line 41, and the specific case is the "Save a village" button (it doesn't update even though the array does)

Comment: The issue turned out to be the fact that I had not declared "parsedText" in the json I load the data from... I didn't think that could be a problem. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a computed property for this, so you never have to manually update the array. Anytime `choices` changes you would see the change reflected in `this.parsedChoices`:

```
computed: {
    parsedChoices: function(){

        return this.currentScene.choices.map(function(choice) {
            choice.parsedText = this.parseText(choice.text);
            return choice;
        }.bind(this)); // bind Vue class as value of `this` inside func

    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but shouldn't the curly brace on the line with `bind` be moved inward?

Comment: and I think you should use the object syntax `parsedChoices: function()` since `computed` is an object.

Comment: Thanks I missed that. @pizzasynthesis